# Counting the number of posts (custom post type) Query problems

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to count the number of total posts of a custom post type "jobs". My query just returns "0" when I know there are posts. I don't think it is checking that the post type has posts, but I'm clueless as to why... any ideas?

```
<?php $jobs = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'jobs' ));?>
<?php if ($jobs->have_posts()) { 

    $count_posts = wp_count_posts()->publish; 
    if ( $count_posts == "1" ) { 
        echo "<h2>There is currently one vacancy...</h2>"; }
    else { echo "<h2>There are currently  $count_posts vacancies...</h2>"; }

} else { ?>
<h2>There are currently no vacancies.</h2>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: As a side note, did you try count($jobs) or print_r($jobs) just to see the original results of the query?

Comment: no, just tried and it doesn't o anything useful.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The [`wp_count_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts) function has parameter `$type` for post type to count, you should use this parameter if you want to get number of jobs

like so:

```
$count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'jobs' )->publish;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace these with your meta_key and meta_value:

```
$meta_key = 'x';
$meta_value = '2';

$sql = "SELECT count(DISTINCT pm.post_id)
FROM $wpdb->postmeta pm
JOIN $wpdb->posts p ON (p.ID = pm.post_id)
WHERE pm.meta_key = '$meta_key'
AND pm.meta_value = '$meta_value'
AND p.post_type = 'post'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
";

$count = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
echo "<p>Count is: $count</p>";
```

Comment: It is a very bad practive to use plain sql in your code. There are a lot of WP wrapper functions that do the same thing and even more.

Comment: @NoSense apart from the built-in wrapper functions are really really slow as they return loads of meta data none asked for. Using SQL is a really efficient way to fetch specific data that you require.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using WP-CLI:

```
wp eval 'echo wp_count_posts( "post" )->publish;'; echo
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue here. Also your example is wrong too!

Comment: Can this be used for posts and products at the same time?